Filtering various VIs by thresholds in GEE
I wrote this script that calculates various VIs over a canopy dataset (that is filtered for vegetation higher than 1 meter). I want to filter each VI by a certain value for example ( -1<ndvi<0.33, & -1<evi<0.2 ,) and finally, find those areas that are common between all filters. I have filtered the indices when they are added as a separate band to an image collection, but in this case, I do not know how. The whole script is here: https://code.earthengine.google.com/b088cbef7fdb7687cfdeff1e0fd7a0fb
var canopy_ht_mosaic = ee.ImageCollection("projects/meta-forest-monitoring-okw37/assets/CanopyHeight").mosaic();

//Non-forest pixels Removal (pixels with value=0)  
var canopy_threshold = canopy_ht_mosaic.gt(0);
var forest = canopy_ht_mosaic.updateMask(canopy_threshold);
Map.addLayer(forest.clip(Border),[],'Canopy>=1m');

var S2A = ee.ImageCollection("COPERNICUS/S2_SR_HARMONIZED")
  .filterBounds(Piemonte)
  .filterDate('2020-01-01', '2023-12-31')
  .filterMetadata("CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE", "less_than", 10)
  .sort('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE')
  .median()
  .clip(Piemonte);

var blueBand = S2A.select('B2');
var greenBand = S2A.select('B3');
var redBand = S2A.select('B4');
var redEdgeBand = S2A.select('B5');
var nirBand = S2A.select('B8');
var swirBand = S2A.select('B11');


// Calculate NDVI (Normalized Difference Vegetation Index)
var ndvi = nirBand.subtract(redBand).divide(nirBand.add(redBand))
  .rename('NDVI');

// Calculate EVI (Enhanced Vegetation Index)
var evi = nirBand.subtract(redBand).multiply(2.5)
  .divide(nirBand.add(redBand.multiply(6.0)).subtract(blueBand.multiply(7.5)).add(1.0))
  .rename('EVI');

// Calculate GNDVI (Green Normalized Difference Vegetation Index)
var gndvi = nirBand.subtract(greenBand).divide(nirBand.add(greenBand))
  .rename('GNDVI');
  
// Calculate GCI (Green Chlorophyll Index)
var gci = redEdgeBand.subtract(greenBand).divide(redEdgeBand.add(greenBand))
  .rename('GCI');
  
// Calculate NDWI (Normalized Difference Water Index)
var ndwi = nirBand.subtract(swirBand).divide(nirBand.add(swirBand))
  .rename('NDWI');

//Masking VIs over the CH>=1 area

var ndviClipped = ndvi.updateMask(forest);
Map.addLayer(ndviClipped, ndviVisParams, 'NDVI');

var eviClipped = evi.updateMask(forest);
Map.addLayer(eviClipped, eviVisParams, 'EVI');

var gndviClipped = gndvi.updateMask(forest);
Map.addLayer(gndviClipped, gndviVisParams, 'GNDVI');

var gciClipped = gci.updateMask(forest);
Map.addLayer(gciClipped, gciVisParams, 'GCI');

var ndwiClipped = ndvi.updateMask(forest);
Map.addLayer(ndwiClipped, ndwiVisParams, 'NDWI');


You can do that one by one or create a mask for all criteria. Then you can stack all indices and use the mask to clip for the criteria. Here is one way to do it
var MaskCriteria = ee.Image(0)
var ndviMask = ee.Image(0).where(ndviClipped.gte(-1).and(ndviClipped.lt(0.33)), 1)
var eviMask = ee.Image(0).where(eviClipped.gte(-1).and(eviClipped.lt(0.2)), 1)
var gndviMask = ee.Image(0).where(gndviClipped.gte(-1).and(gndviClipped.lt(0.2)), 1)
var gciMask = ee.Image(0).where(gciClipped.gte(-1).and(gciClipped.lt(0.2)), 1)
var ndwiMask = ee.Image(0).where(ndwiClipped.gte(-1).and(ndwiClipped.lt(0.2)), 1)
var MaskCriteria = ee.Image(0).where(ndviMask.eq(1).and(eviMask.eq(1)).and(gndviMask.eq(1)).and(gciMask.eq(1)).and(ndwiMask.eq(1)), 1)
.clip(Border)
Map.addLayer(MaskCriteria,{},'MaskCriteria')
var allVIs = ndviClipped.addBands(eviClipped).addBands(gndviClipped).addBands(gciClipped).addBands(ndwiClipped).updateMask(MaskCriteria)
Map.addLayer(allVIs,{},"VIs stack meet criteria")

Edit: fixed an error in the earlier version
